# Selenium chrome webdriver working locally but not in heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have been running a project on `heroku` which uses selenium as one of it's part. This project worked about 2 weeks ago and not working anymore. I have code in place to check for an element and click on it. Everything works on local, I have tested both headless and normal browser on local and everything is working fine but on heroku it times out.
My code for selenium:

```
def __driver_setup(url):
    driver_path = './chromedriver'
    os.chmod(driver_path, 0o755)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=options)
    driver.get(url)

    # driver.maximize_window()
    delay = 40

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-lookup')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Timed out on profile list...')

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="blur-container"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a'))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Timed out on company details button click...')
        return None

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="blur-container"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a')))
        return driver.page_source
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Timed out on company details loading...')
        return None
```

This was working on heroku just 2 weeks ago, it's not working now.
The process times out on every step.
I had saved driver source on a file to see if the `driver.get(url)` is working and getting the initial source, it's working and the button to be clicked is in the source.
I am using `chromedrive version 94`.